# Embedding excel into a gui, for a python program

Tags: python, excel, user-interface

I'm writing a python(3) program that will run on windows only. The program should have a GUI that contains, in part of its window, an embedded excel workbook (and not just its data). Is there a way of doing so with wxPython/PyQt/other?
If not, I found a [way of doing that in c#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15760/How-to-Integrate-Excel-in-a-Windows-Form-Applicati), so I thought of writing the GUI in c# and connect it to python with COM. Can I use IronPython to make a simpler connection? What are the pros and cons of using COM vs using IronPython?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to embed a web browser (QWebView) into the gui and then point it to your Excel Services. The primary issue here, and there are quite a few, is that you'll still need to use something like xlwt to manipulate the data. Unless you have a complex workbook (with macros etc) it might actually be easier to just do something like this using xlwt and xlrd:

```
value_1 = str(sheet.cell_value(sel,4))
self.lineEdit.setText(value_1)
```

You can use labels to add column and row names, lineEdits for values, and tabs for sheets. With a little ctrl+v action (or perhaps a "for I in foo") this wouldn't take as long as you might think.